# Minimize CVaR in Python

Tags: optimization

I am trying to write a simple code for determining the weight allocations in a portfolio which minimize the portfolio's CVaR. Nevertheless, it seems that the resulting weights are not the ones that minimize CVaR. Can anyone detect what is the problem with the below code which does not lead to a minimum CVaR weights??

```
import cvxpy as cp
def minCVar(df, alpha=0.01):
    m,n = df.shape
    t, z, w = cp.Variable(), cp.Variable((m, 1), nonneg=True), cp.Variable((n, 1), nonneg=True)
    RP=df.values @ w
    objective = cp.Minimize( (t + cp.sum(z)/(m * (1 - alpha))))
    constrains = [z >= - RP - t,
                  cp.sum(w) == 1.]
    problem = cp.Problem(objective, constrains)
    problem.solve(solver="SCS")
    return np.around(w.value,2)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would have to show a reproducible example and explain what exactly is wrong. It could be numerical issues. Try verbose=True to see how it goes.